# OSX 10.7 logging

Tags: macos, logging, osx-lion, syslog

With Mountain Lion, I can get ipfw logs removed from /var/log/system.log and redirected to /var/log/ipfw.log by prepending:

```
? [= Sender kernel] [A= Message ip] file /var/log/ipfw.log
? [= Sender kernel] [A= Message ip] ignore
```

above

```
? [= Sender kernel] file /var/log/system.log mode=0600 gid=80 format=bsd
```

in /etc/asl.conf

In 10.7 "Lion", though, /etc/syslog.conf is still sort of used for some things.  For older OSX versions, several blogs and pages suggest adding

```
!-ipfw
```

to the top of /etc/syslog.conf and:

```
!ipfw
*.*               /var/log/ipfw.log
!*
```

to the bottom.  That does get ipfw logs sent to /var/log/ipfw.log... along with crontab entries and some other miscellaneous stuff.  And the ipfw logs still show up in /var/log/kernel.log

I've been playing around with the /etc/asl.conf in Lion, but cannot replicate my solution with Mountain Lion, where ipfw logs and nothing else go to /var/log/ipfw.log and everything else goes where it was going before.